# SharePoint 2016 configuration wizard isn't starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, configuration-wizard

I have installed CU for SharePoint 2016, then I tried to run the SharePoint configuration wizard, but it's not really running. It appears to be running in Task Manager, but doesn't really work.

When I try to run it again, it's telling me that another copy of the SharePoint configuration wizard is already running.

I also try to open Central Admin, and it keeps loading but nothing appears, even if i keep it there for 1 hour. The strange behavior is that when I choose Central Administration option from the start menu in windows server 2016, it tries to open SP config wizard instead.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you reboot the server and tried?

Comment: restart the sharepoint timer service

Comment: What is the logs-file, errors?

Comment: I restarted my server for the 1st time.. and it didn't work.. so I stopped sharepoint timer service and it got stuck on stopping, i restarted the server for a second time again, and tried it and it worked. Now Central admin doesn't respond at all. @MikhailZhuykov

Comment: @JohnZachariah please check my comment above

Comment: @Aashirya please check my comment above

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford Now start Configuration Wizard, then open CA.

Comment: Check the event log for clue, is ur Sal server is up and running? Can you open SharePoint PowerShell? Try to run psconfig from powershell.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford you should check services and app pool, iis websites and then if anything was in stopped mode. Please restart those components. Anything of this should help you resolve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard in a second way: Via `PSConfig.exe` utility. Start a SharePoint PowerShell with elevated permissions and execute the following command to get your CumulativeUpdate-Installation finished:

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, then I noticed that the server was not having space, the database that was used by Sharepoint growed up enough, so I did a maintenance to every database of my Sql Server, a shrink process for each one, then the problem resolved.